# Removing an empty "Row" for a Grid of Nested Divs (not an html table) with JS / jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I made this function to remove rows being looped into in a spec table view when all the cells in that row contain "N/A" instead of a spec. For reasons not worth going into, I need to change my table view from an HTML table to a fake table (html grid) with nested divs. This means that the specs are no longer connected by the tr tag, so I'm not sure how I can connect them to accomplish the same result...

```
  $('.specnacheckrow').each(function() { // for each row in the table
    var naTrue = 0;
    var totalCells = 0;
    var $this = $(this);

    totalCells = $this.find('.specnacheckcell').length //count how many cells
    naTrue = $this.find('.specnatrue').length //count how many <span class="specnatrue">N/A</span>

    if (naTrue < totalCells) { //if the number of cells is greater than the number of N/A's
      $this.show(); //show the row
    } else {
      $this.remove(); //else, hide the entire row - this includes the spec label at the beginning of the row.
    }

  });
```

Example of original table - https://codepen.io/genopeppino/pen/PojMero

Example of Grid Divs - https://codepen.io/genopeppino/pen/oNwKyNJ

You can see that in the original table the "Ship Weight - KG" row is correctly removed by the function above.

Comment: Your `tr class='ddspecnacheckrow'` is now `div class='uk-text-right'` / your new `ddspecnacheckrow` is *not* the equivalent of the old `ddspecnacheckrow`.   If you'd kept the same level / classes, there would be nothing to change as you're already referencing via classes not `tr`

Comment: Thank you. I updated the classes (and fixed some spelling/inconsistencies) to match what you're saying. Please take another look. The problem with this is uk-text-right is referring to columns, not rows. So I added specnacheckrow to that class and added in the same function from the table, but it's looking for NAs within a column, rather than a row. Also, this doesn't solve the issue of the label. In the old table, the row included the label for that row, so referring back to "Ship Weight - KG", the label is hidden with the cells that contain N/A. Still lost.

Comment: I missed that you had changed it to columns rather than rows.   To get a row you would do the equivalent of how you would get a column from a table - you need to use the "row" index inside each column div.   Something like: `$(".col > .row:nth-child(3)")` will give you all the cells for the 3rd row (1-based IIRC)

Comment: Perhaps a step in the right direction, but it's still not right. I tested, and yes, if I add col / row to the appropriate divs, and target the Ship Weight - KG row ( '.col > .row:nth-child(5)' ), it does remove it. But any other row, it will strip out the N/A cells and the label, which is not ideal. Only want to remove N/A cells when all cells in that row contain <span class="specnatrue">N/A</span>. I should specify, content is looped in dynamically from php view. So, I'll never know what rows are totally empty (N/A), which is why I had jQuery targeting each row. But now the rows are detached.